# Javascript fetch - catch error "Load Failed." What does this mean?

Tags: fetch, aurelia

I am using an **Aurelia** web application and utilize the **http.fetch** to call upon various Web APIs.

To help debug I log any errors on the fetch using a catch statement, so something like this:

```
this.http.fetch('Controller/APIFunc', mymethod).then(response => response.json()).then(info => {
            //Do Stuff on success 
        }).catch(error => {
            this.globalfuncs.HandleFetchErrors(error);
        });
```

Occasionally I would get errors with the following messages "*the network connection was lost*"  or "*failed to fetch*" or "*cancelled*" which I attributed to an interrupted network connection and ignored.

BUT lately (*as of Nov of 2021*) I started getting a new error that is coming several times a day, and I do not know what it means.

It simply states "**Load Failed**."

I'm trying to reproduce it but I cannot in my local environment, so I'm trying to find what it implies.

My clients are not contacting me about having any issues, but I'm still troubled by the frequency of this error (coming about 3-6 a day).

Is this yet another type of network interruption perhaps?  I've searched multiple sites and threads and cannot find an explanation for this catch error "Load Failed."

Any thoughts out there would be great!